# Does Console.In has an end

Tags: c#, input, io, compiler-construction, console

**Disclaimer: If this question does not make sense to you, then that;s normal. I am not good at explaining stuff. If you think something is not clear to you, tell me in the comments and I will edit the question! Sorry!**

I am actually writing a compiler/interpreter thingy myself. I have this interface which client code that uses the library can implement so that the language runtime can be customized:

```
public interface ISplRuntime {
    object Current {
        get;
        set;
    }

    object[] Memory {
        get;
    }

    TextReader Input {
        get;
    }

    TextWriter Output {
        get;
    }

    bool Stopped {
        get;
        set;
    }

    void ShowErrorMessage (string error);
}
```

As you can see here, I can create a console app or a winforms app with this. For a console app, I would implement the `Input` and `Output` like this:

```
public TextReader Input {
    get {return Console.In;}
}

public TextReader Output {
    get {return Console.Out;}
}
```

I have these IO properties in the interface is because my language (SPL) needs IO instructions to read input and output stuff. So the implementation above basically means that the language's IO is linked to the console. When a SPL program outputs something, the something will appear in the console. I hope you can understand.

However, I am worried about the `Input`. Because this is how I read a input:

```
/// <summary>
/// Reads a character from the runtime input.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="runtime">The provided runtime for providing input</param>
/// <param name="c">The character read</param>
/// <returns>True if the method successfully reads a character, false otherwise</returns>
private bool ReadFromInput (ISplRuntime runtime, out char c) {
    char stuffRead = (char)runtime.Input.Peek ();
    if (char.IsLetter (stuffRead)) {
        c = (char)runtime.Input.Read ();
        return true;
    } else {
        c = '\0';
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I have another piece of code checking whether it has reached the end of the text if the above method returns `false`. Because the reader may not have reached the end. It might have read a char that is not a letter.

I then thought about what would happen if I called

```
Console.In.Peek();
```

And it turned out that the console prompted me for input. So I think that if `runtime.Input == Console.In`, it will always ask me for input, forever. It will never reach an "end".

Is this true? If it is, please tell me how to detect the end of it. I only want one line of input and if the reader read through all of it, it ends. How can I do this?

If not, when will be the end of it?

Comment: Type Ctrl+Z to generate "the end".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're typing into a console, how can your computer know when you've finished? It's certainly not when you "stop typing", because how do you define "stopped"?

You can treat the `Console.In` just like any other text reader, and check `Peek` for it. The two key things you have to remember are:

1. Input will only reach your code when the user hits Enter. It doesn't happen on a char-by-char basis, it happens at the line level. This is handy because it allows you to type something, backspace a bit, get it right, and then hit Enter.
2. You have to specifically tell the computer when your input has come to an end. This is almost always done by pressing Ctrl+Z to generate an "end of file" character. You will still have to press enter after this so that it gets submitted to your code.

**edit** just noticed that Peek doesn't really work for console input. But it does work if you try to read from the TextReader and check whether that was successful. For the code you have, that is a better way to do it anyway.

Given that `Read()` will tell you when you have got to the end of the file, what you should do is something like:

```
Attempt to read character
If successful, and character is a letter
    process the character
Else
    it's the end of the file
End If
```